I can't store an image CID on a smart contract using IPFS desktop
I have a smart contract regarding collecting data of bridges. the smart contract is created using hardhat and I'm trying to include images using IPFS the contract deployment has been done successfully, but the script used for image storage gives me errors.
the smart contract is as follows
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

contract BridgeData {

    struct Bridge {
        string name;
        string location;
        uint256 length;
        uint256 height;
        uint256 yearBuilt;
        string elementType;
        string elementNo;
        string fcu;
        string ipfsHash; // IPFS hash to store file reference
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Bridge) public bridges;
    
    event BridgeAdded(
        uint256 bridgeId, 
        string name, 
        string location, 
        uint256 length, 
        uint256 height, 
        uint256 yearBuilt, 
        string elementType, 
        string elementNo, 
        string fcu
    );

    event IPFSHashUpdated(uint256 bridgeId, string ipfsHash);
    
    function addBridge(
        uint256 bridgeId,
        string memory name,
        string memory location,
        uint256 length,
        uint256 height,
        uint256 yearBuilt,
        string memory elementType,
        string memory elementNo,
        string memory fcu
    ) public {
        bridges[bridgeId] = Bridge(name, location, length, height, yearBuilt, elementType, elementNo, fcu, "");
        emit BridgeAdded(bridgeId, name, location, length, height, yearBuilt, elementType, elementNo, fcu);
    }

    function store(uint256 bridgeId, string memory _ipfsHash) public {
        Bridge storage bridge = bridges[bridgeId];
        bridge.ipfsHash = _ipfsHash;
        emit IPFSHashUpdated(bridgeId, _ipfsHash);
    }

    function getBridge(uint256 bridgeId) public view returns (
        string memory, 
        string memory, 
        uint256, 
        uint256, 
        uint256, 
        string memory, 
        string memory, 
        string memory, 
        string memory
    ) {
        Bridge memory bridge = bridges[bridgeId];
        return (
            bridge.name, 
            bridge.location, 
            bridge.length, 
            bridge.height, 
            bridge.yearBuilt, 
            bridge.elementType, 
            bridge.elementNo, 
            bridge.fcu, 
            bridge.ipfsHash
        );
    }
}

the deploy script is as follows
async function main() {
    const BridgeData = await ethers.getContractFactory("BridgeData");
    const bridgeData = await BridgeData.deploy();
    await bridgeData.waitForDeployment();
    console.log("BridgeData deployed to:", await bridgeData.getAddress());
  }
  
  main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      process.exit(1);
    });

Then, the image is uploaded on IPFS Desktop and the CID is included the store data script as follows
require('dotenv').config();
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const BridgeData = await ethers.getContractFactory("BridgeData", deployer);
    const bridgeData = await BridgeData.attach("0x5FC-----------------------");

    // Replace with your actual IPFS hash and ensure it's a string
    const ipfsHash = "QmTzKjhGbvcKMmr----------------------";

    // Store the IPFS hash in the smart contract
    const tx = await bridgeData.store(ipfsHash);
    await tx.wait();

    console.log("IPFS hash stored in contract:", ipfsHash);

    const dataHash = await bridgeData.dataHash();
    console.log("Stored IPFS hash:", dataHash);

}

main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
});

and the error is as follows
Error: no matching fragment (operation="fragment", info={ "args": [ "QmTzKjhGbvcKMmrySLvZk8-------------------" ], "key": "store" }, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.2)
    at makeError (D:\Civil Engineering\PHD\Thesis\Blockchain\HARDHAT02\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:694:21)
    at assert (D:\Civil Engineering\PHD\Thesis\Blockchain\HARDHAT02\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\utils\errors.ts:715:25)
    at getFragment (D:\Civil Engineering\PHD\Thesis\Blockchain\HARDHAT02\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:270:15)       
    at Proxy.store (D:\Civil Engineering\PHD\Thesis\Blockchain\HARDHAT02\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\contract\contract.ts:350:26)       
    at main (D:\Civil Engineering\PHD\Thesis\Blockchain\HARDHAT02\scripts\storeData.js:13:33) {
  code: 'UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION',
  operation: 'fragment',
  info: {
    key: 'store',
    args: [ 'QmTzKjhGbvcKMmrySLvZk8------------------' ]
  },
  shortMessage: 'no matching fragment'

I've tried many solutions but they don't work. Please advise.
